# SAS EG dynamic text field

Tags: dynamic, parameters, header, sas

is there a text field control in SAS EG ?
how can i set the selected prompt value ( parameter) into a text field(header is ok too) that will show in the report?
sorry , im new in SAS , so those term im using might not be the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add prompted value to a header.

- First go to the Prompt Manager under View menu
- Click *Add* to create a new prompt
- Give your prompt a name eg. *HeaderText* and a display text like *Text to display in report header*. In the second tab, make sure it's of the type text.
- Open the properties (NOT modify, but bottom option of the right click) of the report you want your text to be displayed in.
- Go to the prompts screen and add the prompt you just created and click *OK*.
- Now open the modify window of the report.
- Go to the titles screen, disable *Default Text* and enter *&HeaderText.* in the text field.
- Run your flow. It will prompt for a text and that text will be printed in the header.

Comment: is it posible if i want the headertext value to be retireved from 1 of the column in my dataset?